# Before confirmation, clicking back button, it is going to previous Screen

Tags: android

When i am clicking back button, i am displaying one confirmation dialog box with yes and no.
But without clicking the yes button, it is automatically going back to the previous screen.
My code part is :

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage("Do you want to exit the application?")
        .setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("NO", null).show();
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return false;
```

means that you're not consuming the back-button so the action will follow the next step:

```
super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
```

Try changing it to:

```
return true;
```

to indicate that you've already consumed the back-button.

Comment: no i remove that return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);        And it is working fine for me...

Answer (score 1):

try with the following code

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage("Do you want to exit the application?")
        .setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("NO", null).show();

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}
```

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: yes..i solve it. I remove that return statement and it is working fine. Anyway thanks Deepak.